# C# Iterate through all classes implementing interface

Tags: c#, linq, types

I have some code which **iterates** through all classes **implementing** an **interface**. This works fine, example code below:

```
// Interface
public interface ICommand
{
    string name { get; }
}
// Test class implementing interface and overrides value
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public string name { get { return "test"; } }
}

// Get all types implementing ICommand; This works
IEnumerable<Type> _commands = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommand)));
// Iterate through all classes implementing ICommand; This works as well
foreach (Type _type in _commands) 
{
    // _type is the type of the class, which implements ICommand
    _type.GetInterface(nameof(ICommand)) // This returns the Type of the interface, if i print it in console "ICommand"
    
    // Here I would like to access the "name" property of the type, but i don't know how
}
```

**Now the question**: As I said in the comment in the code: How can I *"cast"* the return value of `_type.GetInterface(nameof(ICommand))` to the instance of the **interface** of the class, so i can **access** for example the `name` property of for example the `TestCommand` class?

I searched the web for hours now but *sadly* i could not find anything, that answers this

So, any help would be really appreciated!

If there are any important informations I missed, comment and i will edit this post

Comment: If you want to cast to a instance you need to ask your self "Which instance" you can have many `ICommand` implementing interfaces in memory at the same time, you need to have more information to get a specific instance.

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you try rephrase your sentence that starts: "How can I cast the return value...". You have the type, you can call GetProperty (or GetProperties) on it. What can't you do?

Comment: Think of it this way, say you have 200 bags of mixed fruits. I ask you to name all of the fruits in your bags that have stems and you give me a list of fruits back. I point at the paper and say "I want that specific apple" which apple in the 200 bags of fruit are you supposed to give me?

Comment: So i iterate through all classes implementing ICommand and i want to access every name property of this class

Comment: Basically what i want to do is to create classes implementing ICommand and changing the name property so i can then get all instances of the ICommand interface and therefore get all different name properties

Comment: Please update your question with your end goal you are trying to reach, you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), "I have problem X, I came up with solution Y" You asked us "Y is not working, help me fix Y" When you really need to ask "I am trying to do X, I tried Y but it did not work, how else can I do X?"

Comment: *want to access every name property of this class*: you are confusing class and instance (object). Only the instances have property values. There is no way (without a lot of additional changes to the code) to get a list of active instances of a class.

Comment: @KlausGütter Ah, thanks, i understand it now, i really got confused with this. I did not take into account that this class can have multiple instances, since in my case it wont, because it will always have the same values. Thank you, you really helped me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i got the solution with the help of @StevenWiliams and @JimWolff

For anyone who for some reason has the same problem, here is my udated code:

```
IEnumerable<Type> _commands = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommand)));
foreach (Type _type in _commands)
{
    ICommand _command = (ICommand)Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
    Debug.Log("Name: " + _command.name);
}
```

The problem I faced was, that I forgot, that classes can have multiple instances and therefor i cant get the value of the class directly. Creating an instance fixes this problem.

Again, credits to @StevenWiliams and @JimWolff.

Comment: I cant, i have to wait 2 days, so this would be in a couple of hours

Comment: right, i forgot sorry :)

Comment: Thats no Problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is this (using IsAssignableFrom):

```
var commandTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(t => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

To create an instance of an object you can then do something like this:

```
foreach (var type in commandTypes)
{
    var commandObjectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    Console.WriteLine(commandObjectInstance.Name);
}
```

There is a lot of assumptions here about the classes always having a parameterless constructor.

Also, reflection, which is what is being used here, comes with some drawbacks, for example  performance or that things happen at runtime instead of compile time, this is something you should look more, and try to understand if you want to search assemblies for types and/or dynamically creating instances of those types.

Without more background information on why you are taking this approach, i cant tell you if it is good or bad or if you should do something else, but there might be other approaches, even some that might not have much of a downside. In the right scenario what you are doing can also be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing this should get you what you are looking for.  This would depend on the classes that you are loading having a public parameterless constructor but basically you need an instance of the class that you are loading in order to access the name property defined on your interface.

```
foreach (Type _type in _commands)
        {
            // Here I would like to access the "name" property of the type, but i don't know how
            ICommand _command = (ICommand)Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(_command.name);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like @Jim-Wolff beat me to it.  I got distracted by my kid :)